# Bootstrap 3 image over div with left offset

Tags: html, css, placeholder

I am trying to make a card where the image is offset to left side 50%. With the position relative the image is being cropped. The result I am getting is shown in the image.[image]

my css is

```
.card2 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255,255,1);
  margin:0px auto;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 60vh;
}


.dvInsideTL {
  position: absolute;
  left:-40px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

and html is

```
<div class="card2">

      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the 
        industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and 
        </p>
      
          <div class="dvInsideTL">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="" />
          </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you used bootstrap, then why not used column structure

```css
.card2 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255,255,1);
  margin:0px auto;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 60vh;
}


.dvInsideTL {
  position: absolute;
  left:0px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="card2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="dvInsideTL">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and 
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: both divs coming side by side. I wand the image to be 50 outside the background div.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.card2 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255,255,1);
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 60vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: center;
}
.card2 p {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.dvInsideTL {
  
}
```

```html
<div class="card2">

      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the 
        industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and 
        </p>
      
          <div class="dvInsideTL">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="" />
          </div>
    </div>
```

Do you want this?

Comment: With this css the div is showing inside the background div. If I change the last line translateX to -150 it shows top div 50% and cropped the other 50%. It should be outside the background div and should show on top. Hope I do not sound confusing.

Comment: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/components/cards/
Do you want a card like this? Can you show me any scratch for the card?